# How to achieve better accuracy of 90+ on a 3 class highly skewed dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, class-imbalance

I have a 3 class dataset with very high imbalance classes:

```
class 1: 75000
class 2: 27000
class 3: 3000
```

With simple learning algorithms, accuracy is `84.6%` but as expected mostly predicts `class 1`, few `class 2` and no `class 3`.

With techniques, like `oversampling`, `SMOTE`, `undersampling`, `XGBoost`, `Adaboost`, showed some increase in `F1` score, but the accuracy overall either stays at `~84%` or drops.

Any promising technique that I can explore for improving accuracy atleast above `90%`? I am not bothered about improving the accuracy of only class 3, but the accuracy of the overall classifier. thanks.

Comment: If I may ask: why do you need the accuracy above 90%, and what makes you think it's possible to reach this performance? It's possible that 84% is the best possible performance with your data.

Comment: @Erwan because I feel I am a rookie in the ML domain, and I am sure there will be more cool techniques which I am not aware of and worth giving a try. 90% is just my next goal. Goal is to try new suggestions with the intention of achieving better accuracy in all 3 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be careful, looking only at accuracy in a multiclass problem can be misleading: with almost 75% of the data in the majority class, a dummy model which always predict the majority class achieves almost 75%. Measuring performance with micro or macro F1-score would be more informative.

Now about designing your experiments: currently you seem to be trying various methods at random, including sampling techniques and classification algorithms. Why not, but in this way you rely entirely on luck to improve performance. In particular what strikes me is that you don't mention anything about the task or the features (btw it's probably the reasons why some people downvoted the question). The type and nature of the features, their number and their relation to the class can be important to understand why certain methods work and others don't. There might be some feature engineering to do. In particular using feature selection methods sometimes brings great improvement. It would also be useful to get an idea of the performance obtained with simple methods (like decision trees, SVM, logistic regression). Finally you could investigate in more detail which kind of cases which get misclassified and/or study how stable the model is with respect to varying the number of instances or features.